# save changes using Breeze, web api, and entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I am following John Papa's tutorial. When I edit speaker and save, I get following exception. I am very new to this. I really appreciate if someone can point me what I am missing. Thank you!

```
ExceptionMessage=Field not found: 'Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityInfo.AutoGeneratedKey'.
ExceptionType=System.MissingFieldException
StackTrace=   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()


POST URL/breeze/Breeze/SaveChanges HTTP/1.1
Host: URL
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 580
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: URL
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: URL
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

{"entities":[{"Id":28,"FirstName":"Mary","LastName":"Block","Email":"glennb@contoso.com","Blog":"http://glennb.contoso.com","Twitter":"@gblock","Gender":"M","ImageSource":"glenn_block.jpg","Bio":"Father, Husband, Spiritualist, Software geek, Change agent, REST Head","__unmapped":{"isPartial":false,"isSpeaker":true},"entityAspect":{"entityTypeName":"Person:#CC.Model","defaultResourceName":"Persons","entityState":"Modified","originalValuesMap":{"IsPartial":true,"FirstName":"Glenn"},"autoGeneratedKey":{"propertyName":"Id","autoGeneratedKeyType":"Identity"}}}],"saveOptions":{}}
```

Comment: The exception tells you more than we can do without seeing your code. This is a 5-hour course (if I remember well), a bit long to see where a speaker is saved and what could possibly go wrong there. It _looks_ like there is an entity without a key property.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I downloaded newer version of Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6 version 1.4.7 and Breeze.ContextProvider version 1.4.7. Originally I was using version 1.4.5 for both dll. The save works now.

Answer (score 2):

Right, you will need that update:

You can use the Package Manager Console and run the following line to CC.DataAccess project:
PM> Install-Package Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6

My regards